# Trying to compare two dataframes, and writing a logical result to a new dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have an R dataframe that contains 18 columns, I would like to write a function that compares column 1 to column 2, and if both columns contain the same value, a logical result of T or F is written to a new column (this part is not too hard for me), however I would like to repeat this process over for the next columns and write T/F to a new column.

values col 1 = values col 2, write T/F to new column, values col 3 = values col 4, write T/F to a new column (or write results to a new dataframe)

I have been trying to do this with the `purrr` package, and use the `pmap/map` function, but I know I am making a mistake and missing some important part.

Comment: Your description is pretty clear, but to help us all help you please provide a small sample input data frame (3 rows and 4 columns should be plenty big enough) and the corresponding output. I am a not sure from reading your question whether or not you want the result to have the same number of rows as the input, or whether the result should have just 1 row. Or maybe 2 columns with 18/2 rows? An example both gives us something to test on and clears up any little questions like that.

Comment: As an example, following Gregor's suggestion, does `set.seed(1); dat <- data.frame(replicate(18, sample(letters[1:5],5,replace=TRUE)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` match what you are dealing with?

Comment: Thank you Gregor, and thelatemail, I will add some more details with a sample DF. My end result can have the same number of rows as the original DF, but I will create a small sample problem with code.

Comment: *"compares column 1 to column 2, and if both columns contain the same value..."* You mean within those columns, compare each row (/element-wise).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should work if I understand your problem correctly.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(a = c(18, 6, 2 ,0), 
             b = c(0, 6, 2, 18), 
             c =  c(1, 5, 6, 8),
             d = c(3, 5, 9, 2))

compare_columns <- 
  function(x){
    n_columns <- ncol(x)
    odd_columns <- 2*1:(n_columns/2) - 1
    even_columns <- 2*1:(n_columns/2)
    comparisons_list <- 
      lapply(seq_len(n_columns/2),
             function(y){
               df[, odd_columns[y]] == df[, even_columns[y]]
             })
    comparisons_df <- 
      as.data.frame(comparisons_list,
                    col.names = paste0("column", odd_columns, "_column", even_columns))
    return(cbind(x, comparisons_df))
  }

compare_columns(df)
```